# Karate:My Service APi requires client auth certs, The certs are not available in classpath. I have to mount them in docker

Tags: ssl, karate

I am creating configure SSL without classpath. I have to mount certs externally. Following is my code.

```
'''

* def keyStoreFilePath = './certificates/clientcert.p12'

* def trustStoreFilePath = './certificates/truststore.jks'

* configure ssl = { keyStore: keyStoreFilePath, keyStorePassword: '123', keyStoreType: 'pkcs12', trustStore:trustStoreFilePath, trustStoreType:'pkcs12', trustStorePassword:'123' }
'''
```

But I get a file not found, as karate is looking for certs in the target folder. my certs are on the root path. Is there a way to create configure SSL without using classpath?

```
'''

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/kiranjaghni/work/javaworkspace/poc/karateDSL/transfer-case-grid-api-auto/transfercasegrid-api-automation/target/test-classes/examples/login/trustStoreFilePath (No such file or directory)
classpath:examples/login/login.feature:14 ==> expected: <0> but was: <2>
    at examples.ExamplesTest.testParallel(ExamplesTest.java:15)

'''
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the `file:` prefix that can read from the file-system. So then it is up to you, you can have the files anywhere, as long as they are accessible.

```
* def keyStoreFilePath = 'file:/any/absolute/path/certificates/clientcert.p12'
```

Please read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate#reading-files

Also please note that you need to use embedded-expressions: https://github.com/intuit/karate#embedded-expressions

```
* configure ssl = { keyStore: '#(keyStoreFilePath)' }
```